# multiGSEA package in R not appropriately assigning metabolites to pathways

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I've been trying to use the multiGSEA package [Vignette for multiGSEA](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/multiGSEA/inst/doc/multiGSEA.html) to generate a combined p-value for pathways merging transcriptomics and metabolomics.

Even in their vignette, you can see the problem I've encountered- it seems to me that the metabolite mapping is not appropriately assigning metabolites to their respective pathways.

Below, I use the multiGSEA vignette data to demonstrate the issue as I see it. Does anyone have ideas on how to fix the alignment of the metabolite calling to the actual pathways? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

```
library(multiGSEA)
library("org.Hs.eg.db")
library(magrittr)
library(AnnotationDbi)
library(AnnotationHub)
```

### load sample data from vignette

```
data(transcriptome)
data(proteome)
data(metabolome)
```

### The next section is direclty from the vignette, just creating data structure and filling it with the sample data

```
omics_data <- initOmicsDataStructure( layer = c("transcriptome", 
                                                "proteome",
                                                "metabolome"))
omics_data$transcriptome <- rankFeatures( transcriptome$logFC, 
                                          transcriptome$pValue)
names( omics_data$transcriptome) <- transcriptome$Symbol

omics_data$proteome <- rankFeatures(proteome$logFC, proteome$pValue)
names( omics_data$proteome) <- proteome$Symbol

omics_data$metabolome <- rankFeatures(metabolome$logFC, metabolome$pValue)
names( omics_data$metabolome) <- metabolome$HMDB
names( omics_data$metabolome) <- gsub( "HMDB", "HMDB00", 
                                       names( omics_data$metabolome))
```

### The next section is to customize the pathway definitions, and I think this is the source of the problem

```
databases <- c( "kegg", "reactome")
layers <- names( omics_data)

pathways <- getMultiOmicsFeatures( dbs = databases, layer = layers,
                                   returnTranscriptome = "SYMBOL",
                                   returnProteome = "SYMBOL",
                                   returnMetabolome = "HMDB",
                                   useLocal = TRUE)
```

```
pathways_short <- lapply( names( pathways), function( name){
                          head( pathways[[name]], 2)
                        })
names( pathways_short) <- names( pathways)
pathways_short
```

### **Here, you can see that nothing successfully mapped to the metabolome pathways - this is incorrect. I have verified that many of the HMDB values should have mapped (> 300 of them align with KEGG pathways, specifically).**

### **Next, I would run the enrichment scores and then extract/correct p-values. However, because the pathway alignment failed for the metabolome, I'll highlight some of the troubleshooting I have attempted below before proceeding to the enrichment.**

### **I created an annotation hub file to take a closer look at my metabolomic identifiers and make sure they should be mapping**

```
## create a "data" file that shows a key for each HMDB to other identifiers, and merge with metabolome data
ah <- AnnotationHub()
datasets <- query( ah, "metaboliteIDmapping")
data <- ah[["AH83115"]]

metabolome$HMDB <- sub("HMDB","HMDB00",metabolome$HMDB)
merge(metabolome,data, by = "HMDB") -> test
## remove duplicated HMDB values from dataset
test[!duplicated(test$HMDB),] -> test
```

### Try again, but only using metabolome and with the cleaned data

```
omics_data <- initOmicsDataStructure( layer = c("metabolome"))
omics_data$metabolome <- rankFeatures(test$logFC, test$pValue)
names( omics_data$metabolome) <- test$HMDB
```

```
databases <- c( "kegg", "reactome")
layers <- names( omics_data)

pathways <- getMultiOmicsFeatures( dbs = databases, layer = layers,
                                   returnTranscriptome = "SYMBOL",
                                   returnProteome = "SYMBOL",
                                   returnMetabolome = "HMDB",
                                   useLocal = TRUE)
```

```
pathways_short <- lapply( names( pathways), function( name){
                          head( pathways[[name]], 2)
                        })
names( pathways_short) <- names( pathways)
pathways_short
```

### I tried the same thing, but changed the returnMetabolome output to KEGG to see if it was correctly identifying inputs but then failing to output them

```
databases <- c( "kegg", "reactome")
layers <- names( omics_data)

pathways <- getMultiOmicsFeatures( dbs = databases, layer = layers,
                                   returnTranscriptome = "SYMBOL",
                                   returnProteome = "SYMBOL",
                                   returnMetabolome = "KEGG",
                                   useLocal = TRUE)
```

```
pathways_short <- lapply( names( pathways), function( name){
                          head( pathways[[name]], 2)
                        })
names( pathways_short) <- names( pathways)
pathways_short
```

### Now, the getMultiOmicsFeatures is at least assigning KEGG identifiers to specific pathways

### Because I now see pathway values, I tried running the enrichment:

`enrichment_scores <- multiGSEA( pathways, omics_data)`

### Unfortunately, it does not annotate any of the HMDB values I input correctly and assign them to any of the KEGG or recatome pathways

### Next, I tried remapping the inputs to KEGG instead of HMDB

```
omics_data <- initOmicsDataStructure( layer = c("metabolome"))

omics_data$metabolome <- rankFeatures(test$logFC, test$pValue)
names( omics_data$metabolome) <- test$KEGG
```

### Note: There are fewer KEGG IDs mapped than HMDB

### I tried the same thing, but changed the returnMetabolome output to KEGG to see if it was correctly identifying inputs but then failing to output them

```
databases <- c( "kegg", "reactome")
layers <- names( omics_data)
```

```
pathways <- getMultiOmicsFeatures( dbs = databases, layer = layers,
                                   returnTranscriptome = "SYMBOL",
                                   returnProteome = "SYMBOL",
                                   returnMetabolome = "KEGG",
                                   useLocal = TRUE)`

pathways_short <- lapply( names( pathways), function( name){
                          head( pathways[[name]], 2)
                        })
names( pathways_short) <- names( pathways)
pathways_short
```

### Now, the getMultiOmicsFeatures is at least assigning KEGG identifiers to specific pathways

### Another attempt at enrichment

`enrichment_scores <- multiGSEA( pathways, omics_data)`

## looks like it worked, so now I'll extract pvalues and correct

```
df <- extractPvalues( enrichmentScores = enrichment_scores,
                      pathwayNames = names( pathways[[1]]))

df$combined_pval <- combinePvalues( df)
df$combined_padj <- p.adjust( df$combined_pval, method = "BH")

df <- cbind( data.frame( pathway = names( pathways[[1]])), df)
```

### It successfully linked the KEGG identifiers to KEGG pathways, but it fails completely at reactome (or, if I change databases to "all", it fails at almost everything except KEGG)

### I tried keeping the input as KEGG but switching returnMetabolome to HMDB

```
databases <- c( "kegg", "reactome")
layers <- names( omics_data)
```

```
pathways \<- getMultiOmicsFeatures( dbs = databases, layer = layers,
returnTranscriptome = "SYMBOL",
returnProteome = "SYMBOL",
returnMetabolome = "HMDB",
useLocal = TRUE)
```

```
pathways_short <- lapply( names( pathways), function( name){
                          head( pathways[[name]], 2)
                        })
names( pathways_short) <- names( pathways)
pathways_short
```

### But this also fails to annotate anything with HMDB IDs

I have tried different ways of linking the HMDB identifier to pathways. I tried merging with the metaboliteIDmapping and switching from HMDB to KEGG, with some success specifically for KEGG pathways but not for any other pathways.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to the multiGSEA package developer, and he responded that there was a problem where the tibble from metaboliteIDmapping was not imported into the Namespace of the multiGSEA package in the current version. He has pushed a bug fix in the devel and release branch of Bioconductor, so if anyone else comes across a similar issue, use the devel version or wait for the future update.